# Help with understanding なんだかこういうのって

Tags: translation, meaning

I understand what なぜか and こういうのって mean in a rough sense, but I'm having a hard time grasping the meaning well enough to make a sentence out of it while translating something.

The context is that Person A just realized that Person B might not understand the language he is speaking.

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDOD8.jpg)

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0nqf.jpg)

Comment: please show the full quote, with preceding and following information and/or quotes.

Comment: ちゃんと通じたのかどうなのか。
あ。照れてる？
だけど解る多分...　きっと言ってくれているんだと。
ああそっか。 なぜかこういうのって。

Comment: It says 喜んで, not 言って, and it says なんだか, not なぜか.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase 「ああそっか　なんだかこういうのって」 would need to be translated in conjunction with the hand-written 「てれっ = "I feel bashful/flattered/awkward"」, which is used almost like a sound effect or onomatopoeia here though it is originally the colloquial way of saying [照]{て}れる.

The little guy senses the satisfaction on the part of the big guy, which in return gives him a sense of achievement and positive awkwardness.

As in many other cases of J-to-E translations, one would have to use a few words that are not in the original for it to make sense in the target language. My own TL attempt might be something like:

"Never knew something like this would feel so awkward."

Comment: is the use of って here a variant of the quotative って, though here just used to emphasize the self-reflection of the moment? I am familiar with this pattern but only in spoken conversation so I did not know how to define it.

Comment: It is originally quotative as a word but here it is used more like a casual topic marker. it is kind of like は but much lighter in feeling.  The small っ often makes words sound informal.

Comment: Thanks. I had inferred something similar but couldn't find that definition in an online dictionary.